# Chrome box-shadow transition weirdness

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with box-shadow on Google Chrome.

In this gif, it works normal in Firefox:

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

But in Google Chrome it works weirdly:

[image: Google Chrome]

In my theme, every category has a color.
First I am applying that color to li as `border-left` like this

```
<a style="border-left:4px solid '.$color.';" ...
```

And when hover category li I apply that border-left color as `box-shadow` with my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.side-category ul li a').hover(function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 200px 0 0 0 " + $(this).css("border-left-color"))
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "")
    })
});
```

Html code from page source:

```
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i><a style="border-left:4px solid #9b59b6;" href="http://localhost/demos/kisiselblog/category/wordpress/">Wordpress</a><span class="cat-count" style="background: #9b59b6;display:block;">12</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i><a style="border-left:4px solid #3498db;" href="http://localhost/demos/kisiselblog/blog/">Blog</a><span class="cat-count" style="background: #3498db;display:none;"></span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-times"></i><a style="border-left:4px solid #060166;" href="http://localhost/demos/kisiselblog/category/no-show/">No show</a><span class="cat-count" style="background: #060166;display:block;">2</span></li>
</ul>
```

As you see, in Google Chrome it doesn't work normal.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Please share your `HTML` code as well.

Comment: It is wordpress menu, and I am defining it from functions.php file.
http://prntscr.com/g7sj18
But I am adding now my html code from source code anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.side-category ul li a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 200px 0 0 0 " + $(this).css("border-left-color"))
  });

  $('.side-category ul li a').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "")
  })
});
```

Instead of `hover` use `mouseenter` & `mouseleave`.

For responsive `anchor` tag, get the width on the fly using `$(this).width();`

```
$(this).css("box-shadow", "inset "+ $(this).width() + "px 0 0 0 " + $(this).css("border-left-color"));
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Actually I checked my code again and my code was `inset 445px 0 0 0`. The 200px in code is wrong I am sorry. In desktop 200px is enough but on tablets it doesnt fit http://prntscr.com/g7sl4u . When I made it 200px again, chrome problem is gone. But is there any way make the box-shadow 100% ?

Comment: Try this out `$(this).css("box-shadow", "inset "+ $(this).width() + "px 0 0 0 " + $(this).css("border-left-color"));`. Get the width of `anchor` tag on the fly & assign it to `box-shadow`.  Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes it worked very well! Thank you so much :)
Can you add your comment to answer ? I will mark it as an correct answer.